# I need a book recommendation on affine geometry, affine spaces, affine functions!

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, affine-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

I am first year university student and I have four math, two informatics courses. I am learning Number Theory, Algebra, Analysis, and .. Geometry. First year Geometry was okay (2-d,3-d). My teacher was very good at explaining the new concepts.

But this semester I am struggling really hard. I cannot get excited about geometry. It is my professors first year and he is unbelievebly boring. I want to learn Geometry because sometimes it does sound intersting but it is really hard for me.

Can anyone reccommend me a good Geometry book on affine spaces, barycentre, coordinate-systems, affine functions, fixpoints, fixdirections, affine endomorphisms (these are just a few of the topics covered in this semester)?

I tried to find one online but I couldn't find anything good. I probably didn't look hard enough. I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

A very good introductory book on this subject is :[https://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Methods-Applications-Jean-Gallier/dp/1441999620](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441999620)
it helped me in my course. The first chapters are what you probably need. You might find it helpful for other concepts such as projective and basic differential geometry

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check it out!